Math.round(Long.MAX_VALUE+1) gives Integer.MIN_VALUE?
Isn't it in general when we include two numerical data types in one expression, the one with the least bits gets casted into the one with the largest bits? For example, if we have: Integer.MAX_VALUE+0.6, it gets converted to a double.
Now I have tried
Math.round(Long.MAX_VALUE+1)

and it gives me Integer.MIN_VALUE; This means Long.MAX_VALUE is turned into Integer.MAX_VALUE and then overflow occurred. So basically a data type long is turned into an int. Although even the parameter of the Math.round is by definition a double. So Integer in this case is not even a default case. I don't know what I am getting wrong.

Why are you calling Math.round with a non-floating-point expression in the first place?

Interesting: apparently Long.MAX_VALUE+1 becomes a float and is then rounded to int - and i thought i know all about java :-)

By the way… In real work, with Java 8+, throw an exception on integer overflow by calling Math.addExact.

You invoke Math.round(float) which returns an int. The float you pass in represents something close to Long.MIN_VALUE. The closest value of an int that Math.round() could return in that case is Integer.MIN_VALUE, as that's the smallest negative value that an int can have.
If you force Java to pick the long round(double) version by casting the result of the calculation to a double explicitly like this:
Math.round((double) (Long.MAX_VALUE+1))

then you'll get the expected value.

And why does Java invoke Math.round(float) instead of Math.round(double)? Because both long -> float and long -> double are supported widening primitive conversions, and the language spec says the compiler should chose the most specific method.

Since the OP didn't specify what value they expected (only that the actual value was unexpected), it's confusing to talk about "expected value" in your answer. The expected value might be either positive or negative depending on how the OP thought the method should work.

@k314159: sorry, I thought the obvious naive expectation is that if you pass a large positive number -- the naive expectation for Long.MAX+1 -- you get a large positive number not a large negative one. And OP implied they like Integer.MAX+0.6; that DOES give a large positive number and so does Long.MAX+0.6 because both of them do the addition in double.
